# how to model one to many relationship in domain driven design

Tags: nhibernate, domain-driven-design, one-to-many

I'm using Domain Driven Design and use nhibernate as ORM

I have an entity named Certificate and an entity named Condition and an intermediate table for saving one to many relationship between these two entity.

A condition can has many certificates

As condition and Certificates are separate agreagate roots, and based on domain driven rules I can NOT hold an agregate in another and only agregateId can be placed inside it. Thus putting below code in condition agregate can not be true

```
 private List<Certificate> _certificateList; 
.
.
.
 public IReadOnlyCollection<Certificate> CertificateList { get { return _certificateList.AsReadOnly(); } }
```

and the below code seems not true too

```
 private List<CertificateId> _certificateIdList; 
.
.
.
 public IReadOnlyCollection<CertificateId> CertificateIdList { get { return _certificateIdList.AsReadOnly(); } }
```

would you help me to model this relationship?

thanks

Comment: thanks for your reply but I cant understand what did you mean?

Comment: these are two different and separate agregate but i dont know how to model the relationship

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to write a clarification comment and accidentally sent it although I didn't have time to finish. I will find time this evening (CEST) and check back on this.

Comment: thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your business rules, but if there is no rules spanning all certificates of the same condition then you could reference `conditionId` within `Certificate` and rely on a database query to fetch the associtations.

Comment: Agree with this solution.  To the OP, the reason that you would do this would be to preserve the transaction boundary between your aggregates.  While aggregates must remain isolated for both purity and persistence, it does not mean that they believe that they are the only aggregates in the system.  An entity identifier is often confused to be solely a persistence mechanism, and it is not.  All entities should be identifiable, regardless of transitional or transactional state.

Comment: plalx and joseph, thanks for your reply, but I need to have all certificates for a specific condition, and the certificate's condition . Thus apparently I need to put conditionId in cerificate and list of certificateId in condition aggregate.  Is that true design between aggregates?

Comment: There is no problem in just firing a Query like GetCertificateListForCondition to the CertificateRepository. IMO there is no need for the Collection in Condition when there are no invariants to protect.

Comment: > but I need to have all certificates for a specific condition, and the certificate's condition

Why do you need them? Are you trying to enforce any invariants in your aggregate? How are you going to use them? 

That's OK to have those Ids (references on other aggregates) unless you want to load all of them afterwards. It can lead to low performance.